# Android Studio multiple screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, screen-size

I'm developing an app for android devices, but i have some problems with the variety of screen sizes and different densities. So I see that before android 3.2 the solution was to create 4 folders: Small, Medium, Large and xlarge, now this method is deprecated. The problem is though running the application in similar devices the layout looks different. Which and how much folders should i do?

Comment: "now this method is deprecated" Where did you read this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Read the second note from this [Supporting Different Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-bitmaps)  **Note**: Android 3.2 and above supports an advanced method of defining screen sizes ...

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Did you try the techniques described at the link in that note?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did for supporting all screen sizes, it can be a lot of work:

Directories:

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw320dp-land (smallest phones, 3.7" and smaller)

layout-sw360dp
layout-sw360dp-land (approximately 4-4.7")

layout-sw400dp
layout-sw400dp-land (most phones right now, 5-6")

layout-sw600dp
layout-sw600dp-land (7-8" tablets)

layout-sw720dp
layout-sw720dp-land (9" tablets)

layout-sw800dp
layout-sw800dp-land (10" tablets)
```

The same applies to directory names for drawables:

```
drawable-sw320dp
drawable-sw320dp-land
```

etc etc .. that's the general idea

Google's docs mentions sw720dp for 10" tablets but if you want separate layouts for 9" and 10" I discovered sw720dp is 9" and sw800dp is 10"

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Layout Aliases like this :

```
res/layout/main.xml: single-pane layout
res/layout-large: multi-pane layout
res/layout-sw600dp: multi-pane layout
```

But i think the most importing thing to adopt your layout to different screen sizes is to follow best practices for User Interface ( when to use wrap_content, match_parent RelativeLayout, LineareLayout, Qualifiers ... )

Here's a good tutorail to start with [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali)